# How to make a PowerShell FTPS script (SSL) to upload a single file?

Tags: powershell, ftp, winscp, ftps, winscp-net

I need a script  to help me for uploading a single file, to a cloud.

I found some answers with the protocol SFTP (SSH), but I cannot find a script working with FTPS (SSL).

I have tried this script, but it doesn't work:

```
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP\WinSCPnet.dll"
$sessionOptions = New-Object WinSCP.SessionOptions
$sessionOptions.ParseUrl("**ftps**://**login**:**password**@**ipoftheremoteserver**:990/")

$session = New-Object WinSCP.Session
$session.Open($sessionOptions)

$session.PutFiles("D:\QAPPLI\Quadra\DATABASE\PAIE\000001\qpaie.mdb", "/FOLDER1/08h00").Check()

$session.Dispose()
```

I have this error:

> PS C:\Windows\system32> D:\Script\08h00_000001_Client1_to_ftps.ps1 Exception lors de l'appel de « Check » avec « 0 » argument(s) :
>   « Erreur lors du transfert du fichier 'D:\QAPPLI\Quadra\DATABASE\PAIE\000001\qpaie.mdb'.
>   Server sent passive reply with unroutable address 172.16.59.131, using host address instead.
>   Copie de fichiers vers le coté distant échouée.
>   Filename invalid 
>   Au niveau de D:\08h00_000001_Client1_to_ftps.ps1 : 8
>   Caractère : 85
>   + $session.PutFiles("D:\QAPPLI\Quadra\DATABASE\PAIE\000001\qpaie.mdb", "/FOLDER1/08h00").Check <<<< ()
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException

Translated to English:

> D:Script08h00_000001_Client1_to_ftps.ps1 Exception when calling "Check" with "0" argument (s): «"Error transferring file ' D:QAPPLIQuadraDATABASEPAIE000001qpaie.mdb '. Server sent passive reply with unroutable address 172.16.59.131, using host address instead.
>   Copying files to the failed remote side.
>   Filename Invalid
>   at D:08h00_000001_Client1_to_ftps.ps1:8 character: 85 + $session. PutFiles ( "D:QAPPLIQuadraDATABASEPAIE000001qpaie.mdb",  "/FOLDER1/08h00"). Check < < < () + CategoryInfo: NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException + FullyQualifiedErrorId: DotNetMethodException

Many thanks for your help.

Comment: You should translate your error message in English. See also the answer of [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1195462/server-sent-passive-reply-with-unroutable-address-in-filezilla) SO question regarding sending a passive reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `remotePath` (second) argument of [`Session.PutFiles`](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_session_putfiles) is:

> Full path to upload the file to.

While you seem to pass in a path to a folder only, not full path to a file.

This should be correct:

```
$session.PutFiles(
    "D:\QAPPLI\Quadra\DATABASE\PAIE\000001\qpaie.mdb", "/FOLDER1/08h00/qpaie.mdb").Check()
```

Comment: M A N Y   T H A N K S ! ! ! ! !   IT WORKS ! ! ! ! ! !

Answer (score -1):

Using the .Net Framework's FTPWebRequest class from PowerShell, with the EnableSsl property to enable FTPS

```
[Net.ServicePointManager]::ServerCertificateValidationCallback={$true} 
    $Dir = "D:\FolderWithBackupFilesToMove" 
    foreach($item in (dir $dir)) 
    { 
        write-output "-------------"
        $fileName = $item.FullName 
        write-output $fileName 
        $ftp = [System.Net.FtpWebRequest]::Create("ftp://some.ftp.server.com/someRootFolder/"+$item.Name) 
        $ftp = [System.Net.FtpWebRequest]$ftp 
        $ftp.UsePassive = $true 
        $ftp.UseBinary = $true 
        $ftp.EnableSsl = $true 
        $ftp.Credentials = new-object System.Net.NetworkCredential("UserName","Password")
        $ftp.Method = [System.Net.WebRequestMethods+Ftp]::UploadFile 
        $rs = $ftp.GetRequestStream() 
        
        $reader = New-Object System.IO.FileStream ($fileName, [IO.FileMode]::Open, [IO.FileAccess]::Read, [IO.FileShare]::Read) 
        [byte[]]$buffer = new-object byte[] 4096 
        [int]$count = 0 
        do 
        { 
            $count = $reader.Read($buffer, 0, $buffer.Length) 
            $rs.Write($buffer,0,$count) 
        } while ($count -gt 0) 
        $reader.Close() 
        $rs.Close() 
        write-output "+transfer completed" 
        
        $item.Delete() 
        write-output "+file deleted" 
    }
```

Comment: Can you add some explanation about all that code to your answer? Which parts are relevant to solve the problem?